# Does anyone know how to add alerts for anytime the candle in the code shows on the chart in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

[image: Pinescript Code]

I would just like to be able to add alerts for when this type of candle displays on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You already have varibles that tell you whenever your pattern is detected. `kangarootail1` and `kangarootail2`.

Just call `alertcondition()` using them as a condition.

```
alertcondition(kangarootail1, "Tail 1")
```